# next and previous anchors using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page, where answers to all questions are shown and from time to time the answers are updated. I want to have a **NEXT** and **PREVIOUS** buttons that will scroll to the next or previous new/updated answer.

All of the new/updated answers have a label element with `id= new_@i`, where `i` is an index, and `class= "new"`:

```
<label id="new_@i" style="display:none" class="new">new_@i</label>
```

Then, I have created a button:

```
<label class="button" id="nextnew">NEXT</label>
```

And tried to implement the JS part, but somehow the window is not scrolling to the targets:

```
$('#nextnew').click(function(e) {
        var selected = $(".new.currentSelected");
        var anchors = $(".new");

        var pos = anchors.index(selected);
        var next = anchors.get(pos+1);
        var prev = anchors.get(pos-1);

        target = $(next);

        $(selected).removeClass("currentSelected");
        $(next).addClass("currentSelected");

        if (target.offset()) {
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top + 'px'}, 600);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

I have double checked the variables in the JS part and they look fine. Any ideas, what is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works properly

Here is a snippet to show that. If there something that you would like to change, than please write in a comment and I'll edit my answer.

```js
$('#nextnew').click(function(e) {
  var selected = $(".new.currentSelected");
  var anchors = $(".new");

  var pos = anchors.index(selected);
  var next = anchors.get(pos + 1);
  var prev = anchors.get(pos - 1);

  target = $(next);

  $(selected).removeClass("currentSelected");
  $(next).addClass("currentSelected");

  if (target.offset()) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top + 'px'
    }, 600);
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.new {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  background: #EEE;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="button" id="nextnew">NEXT</label>

<label id="new_@1" class="new">new_@1</label>
<label id="new_@2" class="new">new_@2</label>
<label id="new_@3" class="new">new_@3</label>
<label id="new_@4" class="new">new_@4</label>
<label id="new_@5" class="new">new_@5</label>
<label id="new_@6" class="new">new_@6</label>
<label id="new_@7" class="new">new_@7</label>
<label id="new_@8" class="new">new_@8</label>
<label id="new_@9" class="new">new_@9</label>
<label id="new_@10" class="new">new_@10</label>
<label id="new_@11" class="new">new_@11</label>
<label id="new_@12" class="new">new_@12</label>
<label id="new_@13" class="new">new_@13</label>
<label id="new_@14" class="new">new_@14</label>
<label id="new_@15" class="new">new_@15</label>
<label id="new_@16" class="new">new_@16</label>
<label id="new_@17" class="new">new_@17</label>
<label id="new_@18" class="new">new_@18</label>
<label id="new_@19" class="new">new_@19</label>
<label id="new_@20" class="new">new_@20</label>
<label id="new_@21" class="new">new_@21</label>
```

Comment: Does it work properly if the labels are wrapped in div additionnaly?

Comment: @tolik Please post your html that will make things easier :)